# SQL or mariadb gives me this error when I try to create a table

Tags: php, database, mariadb

I am trying to use PHP to create a table in MySQL.
I already have made the database and PHP is connecting to MySQL just fine.
Except it gave me this error and it won't create the table in the database.

**Here is my code:**

```
    <?php

         $servername = "localhost";
         $username = "root";
         $password = "";
         $dbname = "test";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "CREATE TABLE Test (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
testname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
    ?>
```

**The error I am getting:**

> Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ')' at line 4

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the last comma `,` before the `)` .

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
testname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your table DDL sql statement, there is an extra comma (,) before the closing parentheses in your sql.